# checking whether callback is set by the client in C++

Tags: c++

I  have the following class

```
class msg{
//other stuffs before
        void (*callback)(void *);
    bool callback_check(const msg_type_e, void callback);
}
```

the idea is basically to call "callback_check" function to see whether the "callback" is already set by the client. If it is set, then the callback_check will do internal processing, that is why I thought of passing the "callback" as a parameter for "callback_check" function.

However when I tried to compile it, it complains that "callback has incomplete type". What is the best way to check if a callback has been set or not? How to improve the code above?

thank you

Comment: 'void callback' is not allowed. Did you mean void* callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
class msg{
    typedef void (*callback_t)(void *);

    bool callback_check(callback_t callback);
};
```

`void callback` attemtps to declare a parameter of type `void` (unrelated to the `callback` function pointer you declared previously), which is illegal.

`void (*callback)(void *);` is a member declaration of type pointer to function. If that was your intention, you don't need to pass it to member function. You could do:

```
class msg{
    void (*callback)(void *);
    bool callback_check()
    {
        return callback != nullptr;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The type `void` basically means "nothing". And you can't have an argument to a function which is nothing. You have to give it a proper type.

If it's supposed to be the actual callback function, then declare it as a function pointer, e.g.:

```
bool callback_check(const msg_type_e, void (*callback)(void*));
```

---

However I would recommend you to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead, because then you can pass all kind of functions (like lambdas, member function with the help of [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or other callable objects that matches the signature):

```
bool callback_check(const msg_type_e, std::function<void(void*)> callback);
```

Of course you should then make the `callback` member in the class also be a `std::function` object.

---

Now to check if a `std::function` object have a valid callable "function" assigned to it, the class has a [boolean operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) so it can be used in boolean expressions. Like:

```
if (this->callback)
{
    // Callback should be callable
    this->callback(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `callback` parameter is just plain wrong.  It should look this this:

```
class msg{
//other stuffs before
        typedef void (*callback)(void *);
    bool callback_check(const msg_type_e, callback cb);
}
```

Parameter types of `void` don't mean a thing. They are not legal. The only place you can use `void` in a parameter list in C is when you want the function to take no parameters at all `void myfunc(void)` means that there will be no parameters.

A type you can pass to a function is `void*` which is a pointer to `void`, meaning that the type that is pointed to has no type associated with it.  Note that a pointer to void is something completely different to `void` by itself.